# populate vs. autopopulate

Tags: word-choice

In technical writing, when describing how the software performs the action of completing a field on a screen, do you describe the field as being 'automatically populated' or just 'populated'? Does 'populated' inherently infer 'automatically'?

What is the difference between using these two terms, and in what situations is one preferred over the other? Are there any rules to distinguish the use?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22populate%20the%20screen%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: This reminds me of a single-word request I haven't gotten around to asking: What is a single word for the act of filling up a previously empty parking lot with cars?

Comment: First of all, *auto-* means self; it does not mean automatic. An autopopulated field is a field that self-populates. That also makes populating it automatic, but the latter does not imply the former.

Answer (score 2):

*Speaking as a programmer, which I hope is the correct context for this question.*

A field that is autopopulated is one that is filled in without any user intervention. For example, if you type in a credit card number that starts with 5, the form might autopopulate the credit card type field with MasterCard. Or, you might enter your date of birth and the form autopopulates your age field. Or you might enter your ZIP code and have your city and state autopopulated.

A field that is populated is filled in, but not necessarily automatically. You might ask a user to populate all the fields for their address details, for example.

Comment: I would not describe a field that the user enters as being _populated_; I would describe it as _entered_ or _filled in_.  Nor would I describe a field that is set to a default value initially by the program as being _populated_, but as being _set_. "Populated" is most apt for a situation where an array (for example, a dropdown list) is dynamically filled in, either from user input or some external data source (a _lookup_, so to speak.)